# NPM MysqlDump and Mysql-Import , how to add option of drop table if exist , Node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, mysqlimport

I'm using the mysqldump library, and mysql-import. I need to do a restore of my MySQL database, but at the time of doing it, it tells me that you cannot add duplicate files, therefore I manually put DROP TABLE IF EXIST, and it worked and overwritten the database, according to In the Mysqldump documentation there is a way to add the DROP TABLE by default, but I really don't know how to do it, can someone help me?

```
var mysqldump = require('mysqldump');
const controller = {};


controller.backupDatabase = function(req, res, next) {
  if(mysqldump){
      mysqldump({
          connection: {
              host: 'localhost',
              user: 'root',
              password: '',
              database: 'decoracionesalves',
          },
          dumpToFile: './DecoracionesAlves.sql',
      });
    
  }else{
      //Hacer algo aqui.
  }
```

};

```
module.exports = controller;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set `dropIfExists` to `true` on the `schema dump table` option.

```js
mysqldump({
  connection: {
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'decoracionesalves',
  },
  dump: { schema: { table: { dropIfExist: true } } },
  dumpToFile: './DecoracionesAlves.sql',
});
```

See API docs for [`SchemaDumpOptions`](https://github.com/bradzacher/mysqldump#options)

Comment: Thanks a lot! You've really helped me a ton!

Comment: I'm glad it worked. Do you mind giving it an upvote as well @AdrianA

Comment: Sorry bro, I have less than 15 reputation points, which is required to leave votes, as long as I have them I will return to the post and I will give to you, your positive vote :)

Comment: This comment thread is proof that there are still good people on this planet, cheers to this community :).